# firebase realtime database reads json with missing data

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I encountered a really weird problem today. Basically I a populated a database with some values, but when I read that data I realized I had missing data. My JSON looks like the following:

[image: JSON as seen from console]

When I read the data, I realized I was missing the last entry. My code is as follows:

```
database.ref("brands/").once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.val()){
            console.log(snapshot.val());
          } else {
            console.log('node does not exist!');
          }
    });
```

The JSON i received from this code was correct for `Test1` and `Test2`. However, I couldn't see the results for `Yole`.

[image: JSON results from read]

I noticed that there were some JSONs initially that worked out perfectly fine for me, where I could read all the data. I tried changing some parts of it and I managed to narrow down this weird behavior with the following JSONS. The only difference is the entry `1591785585_Yole` (which failed) vs `1591785585_Test3` (which worked).

**JSON that FAILED**

```
{
  "brands" : {
    "Test1" : {
      "1591782657_Test1" : {
        "impressions" : 0,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      },
      "1591789095_Test1" : {
        "impressions" : 0,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      }
    },
    "Test2" : {
      "1591789158_Test2" : {
        "impressions" : 0,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      }
    },
    "Yole" : {
      "1591785585_Yole" : {
        "impressions" : 1,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON that worked!**

```
{
  "brands" : {
    "Test1" : {
      "1591782657_Test1" : {
        "impressions" : 0,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      },
      "1591789095_Test1" : {
        "impressions" : 0,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      }
    },
    "Test2" : {
      "1591789158_Test2" : {
        "impressions" : 0,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      }
    },
    "Yole" : {
      "1591785585_Test3" : {
        "impressions" : 1,
        "likes" : 0,
        "viewed" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hoping that the above will be replicable for anyone who tries it.

I'm wondering whats the explanation for this weird behavior and how to go about solving this please. Thank you!

Comment: I don't immediately see what could be going wrong here and can't reproduce it here: https://jsbin.com/qijebax/2/edit?js,console. Can you set up a similar jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I tried to replicate it with a jsbin - turns out it works, so i narrowed down to a particular function which was causing the issue - turns out to be an ongoing transaction affecting the function, not too sure why